Terraform aws_wafv2_web_acl regex pattern check not works properly
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "main" {
  name        = "main"
  description = "main"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "example"
    priority = 1

    action {
      count {}
    }

    statement {
      not_statement {
        statement {
          regex_match_statement {
            regex_string = "^.*\\..+\\.example\\.com$"

            field_to_match {
              single_header {
                name = "host"
              }
            }

            text_transformation {
              priority = 0
              type     = "NONE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "main"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }


I'd like to count all the request, that don't match domain below:
api.stg.sample.example.com
stg.sample.example.com
admin.stg.sample.example.com

My code works when regex hits header one time :
(this request not logged - perfect)
httpRequest.headers.0.name   host
httpRequest.headers.0.value  api.stg.sample.example.com

My code not works when regex hits header multiple times :
(this request has been logged - fail)
httpRequest.headers.0.name   host
httpRequest.headers.0.value  api.stg.sample.example.com
httpRequest.headers.10.name  referer
httpRequest.headers.10.value https://stg.sample.example.com

How can i fix my code?
even regex_string = ".c." not works

My WAF worked properly.
Just my miss was, i checked WAF log on Cloudwatch (all request has been logged)
I was able to check blocked / allowed logs with log's specific info
